# Tree models in Pyside

Tags: qt, treeview, pyside, model-view

Maybe I'm just thinking about this all wrong, but it seems bizarre to me that **to have a working tree model in Qt, one needs to wrap the data in an item class**.

In all the examples I have been able to find, each model made for a QTreeView required an implementation of a custom Node or TreeItem class (often of type(object)).  This strikes me as odd for a number of reasons:

a) isn't the whole point that the model be able to directly extract the data?  A Node or TreeItem class seems like extra baggage.

b) even if a special item/node class was required for tree view, why wouldn't that class be some kind of QObject?  Most of the Node implementations I've seen have a collection of get/set parent/child methods and attributes; but it seems like using a QObject would have that all built in already, so why not use that?

My intuition (which may be wrong) says to me that if we find we require an extra Node class to implement a tree model, it is because of either a gap in the Qt framework design... or a misunderstanding of it.

I am vaguely aware of QStandardItem and QStandardItemModel but find myself asking why they are part of QtGui and not QtCore, as the other models & modelItems are.  Grouping these classes with QtGui feels like view & model are getting mixed together.  That said, I also don't understand why these are in QtGui either, as they do not inherit from any QtGui classes (they come from QtCore ones).

If anyone can justify this design, explain how I'm misunderstanding it, (or just relate to my frustration) I would love to hear about it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Having implemented numerous `QAbstractItemModel` based data models over the years (decades?) I understand your frustration, however...

> to have a working tree model in Qt, one needs to wrap the data in an item class.

Not at all.  It's simply that in a lot of cases it makes sense to encapsulate a model row in a class of its own -- each column representing a different property of the item (think of how you would implement [`QFileSystemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html) for example).

> a) isn't the whole point that the model be able to directly extract the data? A Node or TreeItem class seems like extra baggage.

You *can* directly get/set the data using [`QAbstractItemModel::data`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) and [`QAbstractItemModel::setData`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData)

> b) even if a special item/node class was required for tree view, why wouldn't that class be some kind of QObject? Most of the Node implementations I've seen have a collection of get/set parent/child methods and attributes; but it seems like using a QObject would have that all built in already, so why not use that?

A `QObject` is a fairly substantial thing.  Given that a model can have (tens of?) thousands of rows and each row can have a fair few columns it's not difficult to see that forcing each "cell" to inherit from `QObject` might not scale that well.

> I am vaguely aware of QStandardItem and QStandardItemModel but find myself asking why they are part of QtGui and not QtCore, as the other models & modelItems are.

`QStandardItem` makes use of -- and therefore has a dependency on -- several QtGui types such as `QIcon` and `QBrush`, hence it must be part of QtGui.

So, as I say, I understand your frustration, but, in the interest of remaining fairly generic the Qt code as it stands is actually very usable.

Comment: That's a relief to hear -- it does seem to me that the data/setData methods should be able to provide the data directly.  However, I'm finding it difficult to see that demonstrated anywhere, even in the official Qt examples.  If you could provide an implementation of even a 2 deep tree model that would help me immensely.  I know that there's methods I need to define, like createIndex() & parent, but how these are used internally (or when communicating with the view) seems a bit opaque.

Comment: Perhaps the thing I'm most struggling with is understanding the flow of operation and (what feels like) a circular dependency.  A data request is passed an index, and that index is coming from createIndex() which is passed a row, col, parent -- and the parent comes from a child, which has an index, but that index is relative to the parent--and I'm lost.